# How to find a template in Alfresco with OpenCMIS from Spring application?

Tags: spring, templates, alfresco, opencmis

I am working in a Spring 3.1 application and I need to find a String template document located in Alfresco's repository. I can already create a file in alfresco with OpenCMIS, but I couldn't figure out how to find a template, so if anyone knows how to do it or point me an example, please let me know, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options you can use. First of all, you need to have a criteria that uniquely identifies your document. Here below I'll show some, hopefully your case falls in one of them or they will inspire you towards a proper solution. The following uses pseudo code, please have a look to the [OpenCMIS dev guide](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html) for working with the Java client API.

**BY ID**

Once you create a Document via CMIS, you get the unique ID of it that you can store in your application for later retrieval.

```
Map<String, Object> templateProperties = createDocumentProperties();
Folder folder = getTemplatesFolder();
ObjectId templateId = createTemplateIn(folder);
storeTemplateId(templateId.getId(), templateProperties); // persist the ID
...
// later on
...
String id = getTemplateId(); // retrieve the ID
Session session = openCMISSession();
Document template = (Document)session.getObject(id);
```

**BY PATH**

Similar to the previous example, you will have to take note of where you stored the document instead of its ID, or having a way to construct the path by hand.

```
String path = getTemplatePath(); // either recover it from DB or construct a path
Document template = (Document)session.getObjectByPath(path);
```

**BY PROPERTY VALUE**

Let's say you can use a specific metadata field on a template Document that allows you to easily retrieve it afterwards (e.g. you created some specific [Alfresco metadata model](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide) for your use case).

```
String meta = TemplateProperties.TEMPLATE_ID; // e.g. my:templateId
String type = TemplateProperties.TEMPLATE_TYPE; // e.g. my:template
String templateMeta = "TEMPLATE1";
Map<String, Object> templateProperties = createDocumentProperties();
templateProperties.put(meta, templateMeta);
templateProperties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, type);
createTemplate(templateProperties);
...
// later on
...
String type = TemplateProperties.TEMPLATE_TYPE; // e.g. my:template
String meta = TemplateProperties.TEMPLATE_ID;
String tplId = "TEMPLATE1";
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM % WHERE % = '%'", type, meta, tplId);
ItemIterable<QueryResult> i = session.query(query, false);
QueryResult qr = i.iterator().next(); // let's assume we have one single match
String templateId = qr.getPropertyByQueryName("cmis:objectId").getFirstValue()
Document template = (Document)session.getObject(templateId);
```

**BY QUERY**

The previous approach is not really tied to search by property name, and can be easily extended to use any kind of query that identifies your templates. Have a look at the Alfresco page on its [CMIS query language](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language) implementation details to learn more ways of querying the repository.

Comment: thanks dude for your explanation, that's what I was trying to do.. now that I have the document, would you know what method of the session object should I use , so I can retrieve the document in a format that String Template can understand?

Comment: do you mean [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)? That might be worth a separate question, as this is more on the finding stuff topic.

Comment: Ok I will open another Question and thank you for the response, cheers!

Comment: Hope it helped! Please accept the answer if you found it useful ;-)